# How do I get these columns to line up with the header in XML?

Tags: android, xml

My table:

[image: My table]

My activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.john.myapplication.Tournament_round"
android:orientation="horizontal"<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:fontFamily="Arial"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/tourny_round"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />



<include
    layout="@layout/header_round"
    android:id="@+id/header_round"
    android:layout_width="480dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/listview"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="480dp"
    android:layout_height="360dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark_transparent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/white"

</ListView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:shrinkColumns="*"
android:stretchColumns="*"
android:background="#c0c0c0">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewHash"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewNic"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRounds"
        android:text="@string/rounds"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewWins"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDrop"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView0"
        android:text="@string/rank_hash"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/nic"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="3"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="4"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:text="5"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:text="6"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:text="7"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:text="8"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:text="9"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:text="10"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:text="11"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:text="12"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:text="@string/wins"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:text="@string/drop"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

My rowlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:shrinkColumns="*"
android:stretchColumns="*"
>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rank_number"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_column="0"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nic"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_column="1"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/round1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_column="2"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/round2"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_column="3"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/round3"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_column="4"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/round4"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_column="5"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/round5"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_column="6"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/round6"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_column="7"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/round7"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_column="8"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/round8"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_column="9"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/round9"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_column="10"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/round10"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_column="11"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/round11"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_column="12"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/round12"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_column="13"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wins"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_column="14"
        >
    </TextView>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/dropBox"
        android:layout_column="15"
        app:buttonTint="#ffffff"
        />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Don't let the absence of other bits of code suggest I've not tried other solutions. I have spent the best part of 3 days trying to get this to format as I want it.

Answer (score 0):

@john better approach will be using linearlayout and assigning a weight to each of the columns. For Name column weight could be increased. The same could be done for row tupples. You would have to work a bit more for this type of UI. I have made this type Of UI using the above approach and using the device width calculation

Comment: :-) My hair is growing back!